# Program difficult to understand

Tags: java

I have a program and I don't understand its result. It gives me `110`, but I don't know how it's even possible. I call it only once. For me, it should be 3?? Thank you

```
public class Test {
    public static String operator (int n) {
        return((n == 0) ? "" : operator(n / 2) + (n % 2));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(operator(6));
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think the problem is recursion, it's string concatenation confused with arithmetic.

Comment: For this you need a debugger.  Put the program in the debugger and go through it step by step.  I might recommend that you separate out all the statements in the compound statement so that you can see the result of each one; create temp vars to hold the results of each call to operator(), etc.  Your initial problem, at a guess, is that you don't realize it's recursive - the operator() method calls itself.

Comment: I don't see any string concatenation in the program...

Comment: Look harder: `operator(n/2)+(n%2)`.  What does `operator()` return?

Comment: This is the binary value of decimal 6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The recursion in this function causes the middle to be repeatedly evaluated with the modulus of the original argument appended with each iteration. So follow the expansion of operator(6)

1. operator(6) => operator(6/2)+(6%2) = operator(3) + "0"
2. operator(3) => operator(3/2)+(3%2) = operator(1) + "1"
3. operator(1) => operator(1/2) + (1%2) = operator(0) + "1"
4. operator(0) = > ""

The recursion ends at the 4th iteration, and the unwound result becomes "110"

Answer (score 3):

It's a simple recursive method, which can be expressed like this to make it more readable:

```
operator(0) = ""
operator(n) = operator(n / 2) + (n % 2)
```

So following those rules, `operator(6) = "110"` as follows:

```
operator(6) = operator(6 / 2) + (6 % 2)
            = operator(3) + 0
            = operator(3 / 2) + (3 % 2) + 0
            = operator(1) + 1 + 0
            = operator(1 / 2) + (1 % 2) + 1 + 0
            = operator(0) + 1 + 1 + 0
            = "" + 1 + 1 + 0
            = "110"
```

Answer (score 0):

`operator` returns a string.  So the result of `operator(n/2)+(n%2)` is adding (concatenating) the string from `operator(n/2)` with the value of `(n%2)` which is automatically converted to a string so that it can be concatenated.

Try changing `operator` to return `int` and changing the line to read:

```
return((n == 0) ? 0 : operator(n/2)+(n%2));
```